# Play MJPEG stream to v4l2loopback device

Tags: ffmpeg, v4l2

I have a RaspberryPi with a V1 camera.

I want to use it as my camera for Zoom, Teams, and other virtual meetings.

I have the RaspberryPi streaming motion JPEG over http using the application named "Motion".

I created a v4l2 dummy device on my linux laptop as a virtual camera.

However, I can't get the mjpeg stream to play to the v4l2 dummy device with the simple command:

`ffmpeg  -i "http://milan.local:8081" -map 0:v  -f v4l2 /dev/video4`

The result is:

```
Input #0, mpjpeg, from 'http://milan.local:8081':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[v4l2 @ 0x55a04567bbe0] Unknown V4L2 pixel format equivalent for yuvj420p
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 --
```

---

What options am I missing from my `ffmpeg` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-vf format=yuv420p` or `-vf format=yuyv422` output option:

```
ffmpeg  -i "http://milan.local:8081" -vf format=yuv420p -f v4l2 /dev/video4
```

Comment: That worked! Why did that work? And why is it only coming through at 1 FPS?

Comment: @ahoffer V4L2 output only supports some pixel formats. Usually ffmpeg will auto convert to an accepted pixel format. I don't know why V4L2 output does not, so it has to be done manually for now. I don't know why it is coming through at 1 FPS. Seems like a completely different issue. Consider asking a new question, show your command, and provide the complete output.